# Lavachart display count each months

Tags: php, laravel, charts, laravel-5

Hello i need serious help cause i have tried all way and not find an answer... so i really want to display chart that count many data each month, ex january 2 data, febuary 3 data etc... pls look at this brother

```
public function lihatkeluhan(){
    $halaman="tindaklayanan";
    $keluhan_list=DB::table('keluhans')
    ->select(DB::raw('id,tanggal,produk,username,area,masalah,status'))->get();

    $keluhan_group = keluhan::select(DB::raw('id,tanggal,produk,username,area,masalah,status'))
    ->get()->groupBy(function($date) {
    return Carbon::parse($date->tanggal)->format('m'); // grouping by months
    });
    foreach ($keluhan_group as $group) {
        $count[] = count($group);
    }

    $bulan = array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","Mei","Jun","Jul","Agu","Sep","Okt","Nov","Des");
    $count = Count($keluhan_list);

    $population = Lava::DataTable();
    $population->addDateColumn("Month")
               ->addNumberColumn('Keluhan');
               foreach($keluhan_group as $group){
               $population->addRow(["jan",$count]);
                }

    Lava::LineChart('Population', $population, [
        'title' => 'Tahun : 2017',
        'titleTextStyle' => [
            'color'    => '#212F3C',
            'fontSize' => 14
        ]
    ]);
```

$keluhan_group used to group by month
$count result is number of data each month
But idk how to display on chart...

Btw $population->addDateColumn("Month") is not work, it not display month but year T_T

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code from `$keluhan_group` to `$population` with below code and check.
here you need to pass array of month and count of that month

```
$keluhan_group = keluhan::select(DB::raw("COUNT(*) as count ,  MONTHNAME(created_at) as month"))
    ->orderBy("created_at")
    ->groupBy(DB::raw("month(created_at)"))
    ->get()->toArray();
$chart_array = array();
foreach($keluhan_group as $data){
    $n_data = [];
    array_push($n_data,$data['month'],$data['count']);
    array_push($chart_array,$n_data);
}

$population = Lava::DataTable();
$population->addDateColumn("Month")
    ->addNumberColumn('Keluhan')
    ->addRow($chart_array);
```

hope this will Help.

Comment: hello again, thank you buddy. i found this error btw, Invalid row property, array with keys type (string) with values [ v | f | p ] what should i change ?

Comment: @Merra Tank in DataTable.php line 841 idk where is it, i guess it is on $population

Comment: ohhh yes 2 semicolons , remove ; from addNumberColumn |                 ->addNumberColumn('Keluhan')
    ->addRow($chart_array);

Comment: ahh nonono i've remove it before ^^ but it still error

Comment: so what should we do with that ?

Comment: @ChristianusAndre, Are you getting error in view file? because i have successfully got the chart in my data

Comment: can u show me ur view code pls ? my deadline is tommorow T_T

Comment: btw can i ask ? why $chart_array = array(); not like $chart_array = array($keluhan_group);

Comment: foreach($keluhan_group as $data){
      $n_data = [];
      array_push($n_data,$data['month'],$data['count']);
      array_push($chart_array,$n_data);
  }
  dd($n_data);

it work now but only show data on April, march is not displaying, i use dd for check, it because $n_data only get the last input after foreach, how to save n_data value into array anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

see i have implemented chart using my 'User' tabel,
i was not having lavachart in my project so i have update it using http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-geo-chart-example-and-demo-using-lavacharts-packageexample.html

here is my controller code:

```
 $users = Users::select(DB::raw("COUNT(*) as count ,  MONTHNAME(created_at) as month"))
    ->orderBy("created_at")
    ->groupBy(DB::raw("month(created_at)"))
    ->get()->toArray();

    $chart_array = array();
    foreach($users as $data){
        $n_data = [];
        array_push($n_data,$data['month'],$data['count']);
        array_push($chart_array,$n_data);
    }
    $lava = new Lavacharts; 
    $popularity = $lava->DataTable();
    $popularity->addStringColumn('Country')
               ->addNumberColumn('Popularity')
               ->addRows($chart_array);
    $lava->LineChart('demochart', $popularity, [
            'title' => 'Demo population count',
            'animation' => [
            'startup' => true,
            'easing' => 'inAndOut'
        ],
        'colors' => ['blue', '#F4C1D8']
    ]);
return view('welcome', ['lava' => $lava]);
```

and in my .blade file:

```
<div id="temps_div"></div>

<?= $lava->render('LineChart', 'demochart' , 'temps_div') ?>
```

Hope this will Help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$companies=Company::all();

$start    = (new DateTime('2017-01-01'))->modify('first day of this month');
$end      = (new DateTime('2022-01-01'))->modify('first day of next month');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('12 month');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

$lava = new Lavacharts; // See note below for Laravel

$finances = \Lava::DataTable();

$finances->addDateColumn('Year');
foreach($companies as $company)
{
    $finances  ->addNumberColumn($company->company_name." ".$company->company_location." total sales amount");

}
foreach ($period as $dt) {

    $yeardate=$dt->format("Y-m-d");
    $insertrow = array( $yeardate );
    foreach($companies as $company)
    {
        $cmp= $company->company_name;
        $loc= $company->company_location;
        $companiesinfo[]=$cmp." ".$loc;
        $databasename=$company->database_name;
        \Config::set('database.connections.tenant.host', 'localhost');
        \Config::set('database.connections.tenant.username','root');
        \Config::set('database.connections.tenant.password', '');
        \Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', $databasename);
        \Config::set('database.default', 'tenant');
        DB::reconnect('tenant');

        $calculatesalesofcompany=B2CFINAL::
        select(DB::raw('sum(GrandTotal) as total'))
                ->where(DB::raw('YEAR(SaleDate)'), '=', $yeardate)
                ->first();

        if($calculatesalesofcompany->total==null)
        {
                $calculatesalesofcompany->total=0;
        }
        array_push( $insertrow, $calculatesalesofcompany->total );

    }


    $finances   ->addRow($insertrow);
}



\Lava::ComboChart('Finances2', $finances2, [
    'title' => 'Company Performance',
    'titleTextStyle' => [
            'color'    => 'rgb(123, 65, 89)',
            'fontSize' => 16
    ],
    'legend' => [
            'position' => 'in'
    ],
    'seriesType' => 'bars',

]);
```